# Semi-opaque jPanels

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make 2 jPanels appear and be opaque after a button click. This mostly works. Both panels appear and are opaque, however they both have the button appear within them. The extra buttons only disappear when I change the screen size (minimize or Maximize). Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jPanel2.setOpaque(true);
    jPanel2.setBackground(new Color(51, 255, 51, 100));

    jPanel3.setOpaque(true);
    jPanel3.setBackground(new Color(51, 255, 51, 50));

}
```

Comment: Can you post a SSCCE? This is not really enough to tell what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to call `repaint()` on the container holding the JPanels or the JPanels themselves after changing the JPanel's opacity. Until the panels are repainted, you will not see any changes.

Comment: Thanks...I should have thought of that

Comment: @LindyKron: no problem. We've all been there ourselves. You'll think of it next time for sure.